# ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

```
import scipy as sy
import numpy as np
import re

from numpy import *

P = np.array(input('Please enter the P vector:\n'))
Q = np.array(input('\nPlease enter the Q vector:\n'))
R = np.array(input('\nPlease enter the R vector:\n'))


print('\n\nP: ',P)
print('Q: ',Q)
print('R: ',R)

#calculations for question 1
PQ=Q-P
magPQ= sy.sqrt(dot(PQ,PQ))
#calculations for question 2
PR= R-P
#calculations for question 3
QP = P-Q
QR = R-Q
magQP=sy.sqrt(dot(QP,QP))
magQR=sy.sqrt(dot(QR,QR))
angle=sy.arccos(dot(QP,QR)/(magQP*magQR))
angled=angle*180/sy.pi
#calculations for question 4
Area = sy.sqrt(dot(cross(PQ,QR),cross(PQ,QR)))
#calculations for question 5
magPR =sy.sqrt(dot(PR,PR))
perimeter = magPQ+magQR+magPR

######################OUTPUT#######################

print("Question 1. What is the distance between P and Q?")
print("Answer: ",round(q1,4))

print("\nQuestion 2. What is the distance vector from P to R?")
print('Answer: ',q2)

print("\nQuestion 3. What is the angle between QP and QR?")
print('Answer: ',angled)

print("\nQuestion 4. What is the area of the triangle PQR?")
print('Answer: ',Area)

print("\nQuestion 5. What is the perimeter of triangle PQR?")
print('Answer: ',perimeter)
```

Above is my code, when I try to compile, I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Homework1-3.py", line 17, in <module>
PQ=Q-P
TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U6') dtype('<U6') dtype('<U6')
```

It's pretty important I am able to input my arrays because I would like this program to be able to solve problems. It seems like its using string instead of float. How could I fix this?

Comment: `np.array(input('Please enter the P vector:\n'))` - are you expecting that to *parse* the string the user types? `np.array` doesn't do that.

Comment: somehow my python updated to 3.x and so it seems this worked in python 2.x

Comment: If you were using this code on Python 2, `input` was calling `eval` on the string (which is a terrible idea and rightfully changed in Python 3). You also had other problems, like using `print` wrong.

Comment: I fixed the print for python 3 because it was the first set of error messages thrown out.

Comment: I removed the np. from array and I still got the same error message

Answer (score 2):

In an interactive ipython(3) session I tried:

```
In [373]: x=input('')
123,232,232

In [374]: x
Out[374]: '123,232,232'   # I got a single string from input

In [375]: np.array(x)
Out[375]: 
array('123,232,232',    # trying to make that an array - still string
      dtype='<U11')

In [377]: np.array(x.split(','))
Out[377]: 
array(['123', '232', '232'],     # better - 3 strings 
      dtype='<U3')

In [378]: np.array(x.split(','),dtype=float)
Out[378]: array([ 123.,  232.,  232.])    # good
```

I'd strongly suggest you fire up an interactive Python session, and test each step of the code.  Get it working piece by piece.  Writing a whole script that has bugs right at the start is not a productive way to program - or to learn.

And when using numpy arrays, look at the `shape` and `dtype`; do not assume that the array is something meaningful or useful.  Check it.

Comment: Thank you, and wise words

although when I try the last line of code I recieve Traceback (most recent call last):File "Homework1-3.py", line 8, in <module>
    P = np.array(P.split(','),dtype=float)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: You apply `split` to a string as produced by `input`, not to something that has been passed through `np.array`.